Sequelize: Unable to Get Associated Resources in Category Model
I'm working on a project using Sequelize and I have two models, Category and Resource. I defined the relationship between them as Category having many Resources and Resource belonging to Category. Here's my code for defining the models and their relationships:
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../sequelize";
import { TCategory, TResource } from "@/types/customType";

type CategoriesAttributes = Model & TCategory;
type ResourceAttributes = Model & TResource;

const Category = sequelize.define<CategoriesAttributes>(
  "Categories",
  {
    category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    category_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    disable: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
const Resource = sequelize.define<ResourceAttributes>(
  "Resources",
  {
    resource_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    url: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    is_active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

Category.hasMany(Resource, {
  foreignKey: "category_id",
});
Resource.belongsTo(Category, {
  foreignKey: "category_id",
});

// sequelize.sync();
// sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
export { Category, Resource };

However, when I try to fetch categories along with their associated resources using the following query:
const categoriesWithResources = await Category.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Resource
  }
});

I don't get the Resource model inside the categoriesWithResources result. What am I doing wrong, and how can I correctly fetch the categories along with their associated resources?

Can you add the attributes and the data types for each model as well? @jagdish Padeliya

@alantrevor : I have added the attributes aswell.

It seems like resource_id is mistakenly defined as primary key in the category model. Also model definition is missing in resource model. @Jagdish Padeliya

resource_id is in Resource model

Please add the generated SQL query for findAll call to the post and also please provide the query output

yeah, it's added. I am getting the products inside the results but the type is not correct. It's showing the Categories Attibutes as type

Your code looks fine now. Probably something wrong with the data? Can you try inserting the data via code and try to fetch it?. Also, this is a side note, Sequelize prefers models' names in singular form link

Thanks for your suggestion. Now I have changed my codebase a little moved all the models in a separate file and associations in another index.ts file. This is working fine now.
